# Вычисление каждого столбца матрицы

Tags: c#, массивы, winforms, datagridview

Есть код, считает первый столбец матрицы

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; ++i)
{
sum += Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
}
label3.Text = sum.ToString();
```

как его модернизировать чтобы он считал все элементы по отдельности и выводил их в лейбл, мне не нужна сумма всех столбцов сразу, мне надо чтобы через запятую сумму каждого столбца по очереди сразу вывел, при одном нажатии на кнопку. Что тут нужно в цикл поместить, чтобы реализовать мою задумку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой способ - сделать цикл в цикле.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; j++)
        {
            int sum = 0;
            //тут пробегаем не по строке, а по столбцу
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.ColumnCount; i++)
            {
                sum += Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1[j,i].Value);
            }
            //заносим сумму в лист, и переходим к следующей итерации
            //не забываем перед этим обнулить счетчик
            listBox1.Items.Add(sum);
        }
    }
```